# Magento 2 : Add product to cart programmatically with custom price

Tags: magento-2.1.4, custom-prices

I want to add product with custom price in cart/checkout only but the original price of product should not get any affect.

So far I've achieved this.I'm adding product programmatically based on some condition. Not using any observer or something I'm just passing product id to my custom controller and adding that product into cart.

```
public function execute(){
    ....
    $productObj->setData('_edit_mode', true);
    $productObj->setPrice(8000);
    $productObj->setFinalPrice(8000);
    $productObj->save();
    $this->cart->addProduct($productObj, $product);
    ....
    $this->cart->save();
}
```

Using above function only product original price get changed but not in cart so what can be done to do so?

Comment: hi @suthar did u get the solution for the above question?

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA: Check my answer...

Comment: could you please suggest me or  help me what i did mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by following

```
public function execute(){
    ....
    $finalPrice =  $totalQty * $product->getKrat() * $price;
    $item->setCustomPrice($product->getKrat() * $price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->setQty(0);
    $item->save();
}
```

Comment: hi kaushal please let me know how can use $item in my controller

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA: $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

Comment: i am  adding the product to cart from the custom controller but u have given the observer code. please suggest me.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Did you manage to do the same using controller?

Comment: @manini yes manini we can able to add a product through controller.  but please confirm me whether you want to add same product price or custom price?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa It depends. Actually, I am creating a quote from admin. So I would prefer that the price of the product should be same as that of my item in quote. Please check my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201995/adding-products-to-cart-programmatically-with-custom-price-in-controller-magent?noredirect=1#comment280849_201995

Comment: i will help you 10 mints