# Adding products to cart programmatically with custom price in controller: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote, quoteitem

I am having a module that is creating quotes using the Magento quote module.

It is using the **\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory** for creating the quotes.

Now I have added a button "**Proceed to checkout**" that should add the quote items to the cart and the checkout page should be displayed to the user with those items that were in the quote.

Here I am creating the quotes as:

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
```

The quotes are creating fine and I am getting the items in the quote as:

```
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
```

I am adding the products to cart as below,

```
$items = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $formatedPrice = $item->getPrice();
    $quantity = $item['qty'];
    $productId = $item->getProductId();

    $params = array(
          'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
          'product' => $productId, //product Id
          'qty' => $quantity, //quantity of product
          'price' => $formatedPrice //product price
    );

    $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);

    if ($_product) {
        $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    }
}
try {
    $this->cart->save();
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Added to cart successfully.'));
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('%1', $e->getMessage()));
}
```

The issue here is the items are getting added into the cart but in case there are products that have a custom price, I need to add those products to the cart, with a different price to what is configured for the products in the catalog.

That custom price is defined in,

```
$formatedPrice = $item->getPrice();
```

Also, I am getting an issue where whenever I am creating a new quote and adding a previous quote to cart it is displaying the items for the latest quote that was created. How can this happen when the quote id is correct here?

I have referred a link that looks similar however, I need to implement the same in Magento 2.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change

Please, can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: let me know whether you are submitting multiple items/products by using from ?

Comment: Please confirm whether you would like to add products to cart using custom form and controller concept?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I am having a controller that will save the products in the quote to cart. Please see the alternative method that I have tried and the error I am facing there.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I tried doing this with observer but I am not getting the desired output. Please, can u help me in achieving this using controller?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add custom price using magento event.

You can see a code in below link.

https://easyprogramminglearning.blogspot.com/2019/01/magento2-add-custom-price-of-product.html